# Get birthday greater than current date

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

my user table is as follows:

1. birhtMonth: int
2. dayOfBirthday: int
3. HireDate: Date

**REQUIREMENT:** i want to get all upcoming birthdays and hire dates (day/month year is excluded here) in next 6 months, putting in consideration that for current month the day should be greater than today, so here's what i did:

```
@Query("from User u where ( (u.birthMonth in (8,9,10,11,12,1)) or (month(u.hireDate) in (8,9,10,11,12,1)) ) and u.company = :company")
```

this gets all upcoming birthdays & hire dates in next six months but it gets birthdays & hire dates in this month for days before & after current day, and it should only get results > current day and ignore results < current day in this month.

**EXAMPLE:**

- today's date is 8/3/2013, if there's birthday with birthMonth=8 and dayOfBirth=3 or 2 or 1 it should be ignored only dayOfBirth > 3 in current month is considered, also if there's hirDate like:

  - 2011-08-01
  - 2012-08-02
  - 2012-08-03

they should be ignored too, please advise how to solve this in sql or hql.

Comment: the answer depends on the database engine.  Please specify yours.

Comment: I 2nd that. Date functions are very different between engines and that is what we will be operating with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hireDate` is of type `Date`, so use a date comparison and use between such as:

```
(hireDate between :toDayParam and :sixMonthLaterParam)
```

for birthDate, you can compare with `lpad(birthMonth, 2, 0) + lpad(birthDate, 2, 0)` but you shall care about whether six month later is in next year or current year.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the DATE functions. They can greatly help you out here. Specifically the DATEADD function. Take a look at the code I made here.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.product 
WHERE dbo.product.stockDate > GETDATE()
AND dbo.product.stockDate < GETDATE() + DATEADD(month, 6, dbo.product.stockDate)
AND dbo.product.expirationDate > GETDATE()
AND dbo.product.expirationDate < GETDATE() + DATEADD(month, 6, dbo.product.expirationDate)
```

This will guarantee that the stockDate and the expirationDate are greater than the current date and less than the current date + 6 mo. DATEADD works as follows DATEADD(-what you want to increment by-, -how much you want to increment-, -date to add to-).